# How to read Delve profile info from the Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

May I know how can I get **About Me** information for a specified user available in Microsoft Delve through the Graph API?

[image: About Me info available from Delve]

Comment: I dont remember there is a single Graph API call available. Being said that i would start it from https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ and combine the related values. If you are looking for any specific value and if its not available, "Ask it"

Comment: @Dev Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, the information which I require as highlighted in the above image can't be obtained from graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me endpoint. Is there any other way I can obtain that About me information?

Comment: If it's not in me, then the closest one i remember is /profile API call. But i dont see explicit reference in API call as well. But i am sharing the doc on best effort basis:- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/profile?view=graph-rest-beta

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually found it in the profile API call and I have posted the actual API call in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The About Me information from Delve can be found from this beta profile API call -

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/id/profile/notes